# Twilio TaskRouter: change worker activity when disconnected

Tags: javascript, twilio

Let's say worker X logged in to our call center app and went online in twilio. He will now be able to receive reservations and respond to people. X lives in a third world country where the internet connection is very unreliable. His internet suddenly cut off while online and he is no longer able to respond to reservations. His activity is still `Online` and he has no way of changing it because he doesn't have an internet connection. Is there a way to tell twilio to go `Offline` when the WebSocket connection is lost between the client and the server?

I'm aware that we have `disconnectActivitySid` in TaskRouter.js but it is only fired on `window.unload` event and doesn't cover the cases where the browser crashes or we have internet connectivity problems.

Comment: Is this a feature request for Twilio or something that you have tried to achieve and need help implementing? Can you share some code?

Comment: Hey @philnash! Thank you for your response, i updated the question to be clearer.

Comment: Cheers, I'm just checking with our team about this. Will get back to you soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The only way to do this today would be to have the Worker receive a next Reservation, but have a [Workflow ReservationTimeout](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/workflows#resource-properties) of a semi-low value (10-15 seconds) and to utilize the [Workspace’s TimeoutActivitySid](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/workspaces#resource-properties) to push the Worker to Offline.

With that setup, if the Worker loses connection (but is Idle), and receives a Reservation and is able to reconnect before that Reservation Times out (in that 15 second window), they will presented the Reservation with the JS SDK. So nothing will be lost. If they do not reconnect within that timeout window, the Worker will be pushed to Offline, and another Worker will be eligible to pick up the Task.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Now is there any options in Twilio to watch for workers' device statuses in real time?